# Traefik with Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker-swarm, traefik

I am not sure if this is possible because I do not have control over the DNS (I can edit /etc/hosts though).

I have a few Azure Ubuntu servers running with 1 manager and 2 workers (3 total). These nodes are only accessible on our corporate network. I typically access web portals from my desktop at the office by typing:

- IP-Address:Port
- Host:Port
- Host.corp.companyname.com:Port

My goal is to instead type something like **host/pgadmin** or **host/portainer** to be routed to a web portal which is running on the worker nodes. Is it possible? I don't mind editing my desktop's /etc/hosts file but I don't want to specify an IP address (otherwise there is no point in having the portal run on multiple nodes).

```
services:
  web:
    image: traefik:1.7-alpine
    networks:
      - frontend
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    command:
      - --docker
      - --docker.swarmMode
      - --docker.domain=corp.companyname.com
      - --docker.watch
      - --api
      - --defaultentrypoints=http
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: 
          - node.role == manager


  pgadmin4:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.0
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    deploy:
      placement: 
        constraints: 
          - node.role == worker
      labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=frontend
      - traefik.backend=pgadmin4
      - traefik.port=5050
      - traefik.frontend.rule=???????
    networks:
      - frontend

networks:
  frontend:
    external: true
    name: frontend
```

Answer (score 0):

You can totally do it with

```
  - traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/pgadmin/
```

[Here](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#frontends) is a list of matchers that traefik can work with.

Comment: in the traefik file, is the domain: --docker.domain=corp.companyname.com or should I use docker.localhost or something? I am currently accessing traefik by going to SwarmManagerIPAddress:8080/dashboard.

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: I added these labels (frontend is an overlay network). I tried accessing http://IP:8080/pgadmin but it didn't work. The backend servers I see are not real IP addresses I can connect to (10.0.8.31:5050).       labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=frontend
      - traefik.backend=pgadmin4
      - traefik.port=5050
      - traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/pgadmin/

Comment: why do you mount  ` - /dev/null:/traefik.toml`?

Comment: Saw it in an example: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/2298

Comment: can you provide log in debug mode so we can better understand the situation?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work finally.

1. I had to rename my traefik.docker.network from frontend to traefik_frontend (traefik was the name I used when I ran the stack deploy command)
2. I had to use Firefox (Chrome would not work - I have no idea why)
3. I changed the traefik.port=5050 to traefik.port=80
4. I added traefik-pgadmin.docker.localhost to my /etc/hosts file on windows (and noticed before I was saving it as .txt file which was wrong)